# How to change HERE maps type in SAP Visual Business GeoMap?

Tags: sapui5, here-api

According to this [Map Provider Configuration Changes](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SVE/Map+Provider+Configuration+Changes), I use this configuration to add HERE maps in GeoMap:

```
var oMapConfig = {
  "MapProvider": [{
    "name": "HEREMAPS",
    "type": "HERETerrainMap",
    "description": "",
    "tileX": "256",
    "tileY": "256",
    "maxLOD": "20",
    "copyright": "Tiles Courtesy of HERE Maps",
    "Source": [{
        "id": "s1",
        "url": "https://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/reduced.day/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}/256/png8?app_id=MY_ID&app_code=MY_CODE"
      }, {
        "id": "s2",
        "url": "https://2.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/reduced.day/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}/256/png8?app_id=MY_ID&app_code=MY_CODE"
      }
    ]
  }],
  "MapLayerStacks": [{
    "name": "DEFAULT",
    "MapLayer": {
      "name": "layer1",
      "refMapProvider": "HEREMAPS",
      "opacity": "1.0",
      "colBkgnd": "RGB(255,255,255)"
    }
  }]
};
this.oMap.setMapConfiguration(oMapConfig);
this.oMap.setRefMapLayerStack("DEFAULT");
```

But my map is in black and white style:

[image]

What I want is standard map:

[image]

In [Configuring HERE (formerly Nokia, NAVTEQ) maps](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SVE/Configuring++HERE+%28formerly+Nokia%2C+NAVTEQ%29+maps), new server URL is provided, I've tried this, but not working.

```
{
  "id": "s1",
  "url": http://1.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}/256/png?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE"
}, {
  "id": "s2",
  "url": "http://2.maps.nlp.nokia.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/{LOD}/{X}/{Y}/256/png?app_id=MY_APP_ID&app_code=MY_APP_CODE"
}
```

And failed to find MapProvider configuration documentation in [setMapConfiguration of GeoMap](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.vbm.GeoMap/methods/setMapConfiguration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `reduced.day` to `normal.day` in your map URL, and you'll get colored map:)

edit:

Please refer to https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/examples.html for detailed APIs